# an olive is ‘pitted’: adjective or verb?

Tags: verbs, adjectives

‘pitted olives’, peeled carrots’, ‘cobbed corn’

I mean, at first glance they’re of course adjectives followed by nouns; but are they? Isn’t the word ‘pitted’ in this case describing the action taken upon the olive?

Do we assume it’s an adjective because it’s written on an object found in the grocery store?

[image]

Comment: It's used as an adjective. Cf. *burnt* in "Burnt Weeny Sandwich" &c.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They're adjectives. The action of removing an olive's pit is "pitting", and an olive that has been pitted is called a pitted olive. You can further tell that this is an adjective by its purpose for appearing on the label, which is to distinguish these olives by describing them. Also by noting that no one or nothing is actually performing any action; the label is simply telling you that the olives are pitted, not that "[name or thing unknown] once pitted them". Adjectives which describe the action of a verb frequently take the same form as the verb's past tense. That doesn't make them any less adjective. See "the dotted line", "the ruined house", or "the sealed door", where all the descriptors fit the pattern and are very, very clearly adjectives.

Comment: I'd like to know why this answer has been downvoted. If someone doesn't agree with it they should say why. Just downvoting gives no one any opportunity for learning which is, surely, the point of this site. I've just upvoted it, please tell me why I shouldn't have done.

Comment: As an example of the difference between the past participle of a word being used as a verb and as an adjective consider two lines from the Rolling Stones hit _Paint it Black_: "I see a red door and I want it painted black" (verb, he wants someone to take action to apply paint to the door) and "I see a line of cars and they're all painted black" (adjective, the cars had the paint applied when they were built or shortly afterwards but are now cars which have been, at some time, painted black)

Comment: @BoldBen I didn't downlote but I can see why someone might: R Mac's test for adjectivehood are not reliable. Not every word that modifies a noun is an adjective. Not even every word used for the purpose of distinguishing. One may distinguish some oil from other oil by calling it olive oil; this doesn't make "olive" an adjective. "Pitted" fails some tests for adjectivehood in that it can't take -er or -est, nor "more" or "most", or "very" or "somewhat".

Comment: @RosieF The "test" is indeed not reliable but to be fair to R Mac, they do not propose a general test for adjectivity; they merely explain why *pitted* is usable in this context. Perhaps the downvoter has other reasons they may like to explain? The PO omitted to show any of their own research on the matter.

Comment: @RosieF I did not intend to provide a test that something is an adjective. It's more a test that it's not a verb. And yes, all words which describe nouns are adjectives. That's the definition of "adjective". In the examples given, "olive" *is* acting as an adjective because it describes "oil". Together they also make what we call a compound noun, and you frequently see words which normally act as nouns acting as adjectives in these constructions (e.g., "substitute teacher", "construction worker", "oat milk"). These all expound on the question, "What kind of [thing]?' If the shoe fits, wear it.

Comment: @RMac  It's not true that "all words which describe nouns are adjectives". Nouns can be modified by a wide range of expressions other than adjectives, for example verb phrases, determinative phrases, adverbs, nominals, appositives, preposition phrases and clauses. We certainly don't want to call them adjectives!

Comment: @BillJ You're blowing smoke. Verb phrases and adverbs have nothing to do with nouns (except for when they have a subject or an object), and prepositional phrases and appositives can and often do act as adjectives. Parts of speech aren't always exclusive especially when talking about phrases.

Comment: @RMac I've just told you that VPs, PPs and appositives when they function as modifiers of nouns are **not** adjectives. Adjective is a word class (POS) whose members include such words as "red", "old", "new, "empty". You're conflating category and function. Adjectives and determinatives aside, the other dependents of a noun are **modifiers** (or complements) not adjectives.

Comment: @RMac Consider these examples: "a sleeping child" ("sleeping" is a VP modifying "child". "a brick wall" ("brick" is a nominal modifying "wall"). The same applies with post-head modifiers: "a tree by the gate" (PP "by the gate" modifying "tree"). "the opera Carmen" ("Carmen" is an appositive NP modifying "opera". "Some people [I met on train]" (relative clause modifying "people") and so on.

Comment: Adjective is not a word class. It's a part of speech. It depends entirely on the syntactic role of a word or phrase in an expression and is not a quality of the word or phrase independently of the expression under consideration.

Comment: @RMac Of course 'adjective' is a 'word class' (or 'part of speech'). wWhat else could it be? Some people prefer the term 'part of speech', others 'word class', but they are interchangeable. Function (your 'role') is a relative term used to describe such things as subject, object, modifier, complement etc. In, for example "I like beer", "beer" belongs to the word class (POS) **noun**, and its function is **object** of the verb "like". And in "Kim seems nice", "nice" belongs to the word class (POS) adjective and its function is **complement** of the verb "be". Now do you see?

Comment: See here: [link](https://www.lexico.com/grammar/word-classes-or-parts-of-speech)